# Can I safely delete the "browser" icon if I use Chrome?

Tags: browser

I have a Samsung SM-G313H.

Can I delete the actual ''browser'' icon on my Samsung phone as when I tap on it there comes a whole screen of errors.  I can get onto the internet by using the chrome icon.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you wish to delete it from:

- **Homescreen:** Tap and hold the icon, then move it to the trash can (which usually appears on the upper border of your screen). This just removes the icon from your homescreen, and you could re-add it any time by long-pressing it in the app-drawer and let it go on the homescreen). Very safe to do.
- **From the app drawer:** This is the list of all apps available, and you usually cannot *directly* remove anything here. Instead, unless the launcher offers you to "hide" items (some do, e.g. *Apex* or *Nova* – I'm not sure for the default TouchWiz launcher as I don't use a Samsung smartphone), you need to uninstall the corresponding user-app or, in case of a system app, disable it. For this, go to *Settings › Apps › All*, scroll to the app in question (here: the browser), tap the entry (which opens the details page for the app), and tap either the "uninstall" or "disable" button.

You can of course re-install an app (as long as it is available), and you definitely can "enable" a disabled app again (same procedure, the button will now be named "enable") – so this usually is safe enough, though you'll receive a warning of possible side-effects. Critical components (e.g. "Android System") cannot be disabled anyway ;)

Comment: Stock TouchWiz doesn't allow to hide icons listed in the app drawer.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman thought so. Thanks for confirmation! So my instructions are correct :)